# ID process making HTTP request

Tags: networking, ps, netstat, traffic, tcpdump

My firewall is detecting my ubuntu server calling a URL on port 80 sporadically. I'd like to ID the process making the callout, but the connection is always gone by the time I can run a netstat.

A lot of the usual network tools (iptables, tcpdump) seem to only catch the traffic, not the process.

I would like a way to catch this process calling out so I can ID it and put a stop to it or understand why it's doing it (it's calling fortnitecontent-website-prod07.ol.epicgames.com, which makes zero sense to me as it's the mediaserver with no games being played on it).

Thanks!